# How to change the delimiter of QualifiedNames

Tags: xtext

I want to change the delimiter of the QualifiedName from '.' to '#'. Below is my try. The following example from the online documentation.

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Domainmodel:
    (elements+=AbstractElement)*;
 
PackageDeclaration:
    'package' name=QualifiedName '{'
        (elements+=AbstractElement)*
    '}';
 
AbstractElement:
    PackageDeclaration | Type;
 
QualifiedName:
    ID ('#' ID)*;
 
Type:
    DataType | Entity;
 
DataType:
    'datatype' name=ID;
 
Entity:
    'entity' name=ID ('extends' superType=[Entity|QualifiedName])? '{'
        (features+=Feature)*
    '}';
 
Feature:
    (many?='many')? name=ID ':' type=[Type|QualifiedName];
```

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl

import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.IQualifiedNameConverter
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider

/**
 * Use this class to register components to be used at runtime / without the Equinox extension registry.
 */
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {
    override  bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
        return MyDslQualifiedNameProvider
    }
    
}

class MyDslQualifiedNameProvider extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {
    val converter = new MyDslQualifiedNameConverter();
    
    override getConverter(){
        converter
    }
    
}

class MyDslQualifiedNameConverter extends IQualifiedNameConverter.DefaultImpl {
    override getDelimiter() {
            return "#";
    }
}
```

I could not refer any *Entity* in a package such as "my#company#blog#Blog" in the following. IDE suggests the expression "my#company#blog.Blog" but that doesn't work either.

```
datatype String
package my#company#blog{ 
    entity Blog{
        title : String
    }
}
entity Blog2 extends my#company#blog#Blog{
    title : String
}
```

Comment: is there a reason you use "new" for the qualified name converter and not guice? what about the 50 other places that use it?

Comment: Thanks Christian. I solved the problem as the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guice usage solves. Following is how is done. There is no bind method to override in 'AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule'. Parent class, 'AbstractGenericModule', does the trick via 'getBindings' method of itself.

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {
    def Class<? extends IQualifiedNameConverter> bindIQualifiedNameConverter() {
        return MyDslQualifiedNameConverter;
    }
}
class MyDslQualifiedNameConverter extends IQualifiedNameConverter.DefaultImpl {
    override getDelimiter() {
            return "#";
    }
}
```